# Cassandra lower vtokens

Tags: cassandra, cluster-computing, cql

We have the need to reduce vtokens on a Cassandra cluster (2 nodes) to compensate for both machines having different storage capabilities. The replication factor is currently 1 so there is no replication of data happening.

Can't we simple reduce vtokens to 32 instead of current 256 and restart server? What'll happen if we try this? Will it stream the extra tokens or will we loose data?

We read about decommissioning the node to copy all data to the bigger one, reconfigure it to have less vtokens, delete cassandra data locally and make it rejoin the cluster, just wondering what happens if we try to reduce vtokens before decommissioning it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you aware how dangerous it is to run with RF=1? The main point of Cassandra is high availability which you lose in that scenario with data loss likely with any kind of failure, even just a kill -9.

Comment: Yes we're aware of that. But we only have 2 machines available at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do balancing with vnodes. By virtue of statistics you should have a pretty even distribution of data across your nodes even with 32 vnodes. And fewer vnodes will give you better search performance.

Also keep an eye on CASSANDRA-7032, this should let us go to even lower num_tokens without sacrificing data distribution.

Comment: Balancing with vnodes is possible, we have a cluster running with 32 vtokens on one machine, 256 vtokens on the other (15% - 85% distribution).